# Module build failed: Error: Typescript emitted no output for

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

When I try to compile a .ts file I get the following error:

```
Module build failed: Error: Typescript emitted no output for C:\xampp\htdocs\node-api\src\js\server.ts. 
at successLoader (C:\xampp\htdocs\node-api\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:39:15)
at Object.loader (C:\xampp\htdocs\node-api\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:21:12)
```

For compiling I use the following config files.

Webpack:

```
const path = require( 'path' ),
    CleanWebpackPlugin = require( 'clean-webpack-plugin' );

module.exports = env => {
    return {
        mode: env.dev ? 'development' : 'production',
        entry: {
            'server': './src/js/server.ts'
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname,
            filename: './dist/js/[name].js',
        },
        externals: '/node_modules',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: ['/node_modules/', '/src/scss/'],
                    use: [
                        'babel-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                    exclude: ['/node_modules/', '/src/scss/'],
                    use: [
                        'babel-loader',
                        'ts-loader',
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test:  /\.json$/,
                    loader: 'json-loader'
                },
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ],
            alias: {
                '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js')
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            new CleanWebpackPlugin(['./dist/js', './dist/css']),
        ]
    }
};
```

Typescript:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/js",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "es2015",
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "es2016"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Babel:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "env", {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ],
        "stage-2", "es2015"
    ],
    "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
}
```

As suggested in some other questions I've already changed the order of resolve extensions but that didn't solve it (`.js` before `.ts`) . Typescript 2.8.3 is used in combination with Node 8.11.1 and Mongoose 5.0.15 and compiled by Webpack 4.6. So I'm still wondering how to to solve the error mentioned above.

Comment: Post your tsconfig.json

Comment: @Sajeetharan its under `Typescript:`

Comment: can you try adding "files": [
    "./src/components/index.d.ts"
] to your tsconfig

Comment: @Sajeetharan Tried that but also didn't work

Comment: ok what about  index.ts  instead of index.d.ts

Comment: That index.d.ts is from node_modules or atleast it's not a file that I created. Could it also be something that is in the server.ts file?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to import all your modules something like this: import * as express from 'express', and also try setting your module property in typeconfig.json to commonjs.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `outDir` as tsc doesn't emit anything if it's on?

Answer (score 33):

Please set `noEmit` to `false` in your `tsconfig.json`.
By default it sets to `true`, once we change it to `false` we may not get this error.

`"noEmit": false`

Comment: Try adding this as comment or elaborate your answer.

Comment: But... but... why?

Comment: yes, this works but why?

Answer (score 10):

Override `compilerOptions` like this in webpack config (when using `ts-loader`):

```js
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[jt]s$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              compilerOptions: {
                noEmit: false,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
```

Comment: this option is not available to be set in webpack.config.json, Webpack version 5.47

Comment: I like this option, since it allows `noEmit: true` in tsconfig, which prevents output except during build. @BEvo it is available, but you may need to change `use: 'ts-loader'` to `loader: 'ts-loader'`.

Comment: This worked for me on Cypress plugins file setting up the `ts-loader` preprocessor for cucumber `.feature` files: `on(
    'file:preprocessor',
    webpack({
      webpackOptions: {
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        },
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.ts$/,
              exclude: [/node_modules/],
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'ts-loader',
                  options: {
                    compilerOptions: {
                      noEmit: false,
                    }...`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to remove `"emitDeclarationOnly": true` from the `tsconfig.json`

(or just set it to `false`)

With this on, it will only output `d.ts` files and not JavaScript files.

Read more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#emitDeclarationOnly

Comment: Exactly! That is the correct answer. Using webpack 5.76 and ts-loader 9.4 here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using webpack 5 and Typescript 4.5, I can run an expressjs + prisma server with the following:

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              compilerOptions: {noEmit: false},
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Source: https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/