# How to enable a SharedRuntime Environment in a custom function excel add-in with a separate vuejs taskpane

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, office-js

**What I need to do:**

Create a shared runtime environment so that my excel custom functions can have access to the workbook information.

Current Setup:
The way the project seems to have been set up is, using the yeoman office generator to generate a custom function addin and then using vue-cli to generate a vue app to use as the taskpane.

**Folder Structure:**

```
RootFolder
Add-In
    dist
    node_modules
    src
    config.json
    manifest.xml
    jest.config.js
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    webpack.config.js
Taskpane
    dist
    public
    node_modules
    src
        assets
        modules
        plugins
        router
        store
        views
        App.vue
        main.ts
        shims-vue.d.ts
        shims.tsx.d.ts
        shims.vuetify.d.ts
    .browserlistrc
    .eslintrc.js
    babel.config.js
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
    vue.config.js
```

Webpack config for addin prior to changes:

```
  module.exports = async (env, options) => {
  const dev = options.mode === "development";
  const buildType = dev ? "dev" : "prod";
  const config = {
    node: {
      fs: 'empty' // https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/447
    },
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      functions: "./src/functions/functions.ts",
      polyfill: "@babel/polyfill",
      commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts"
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "babel-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "ts-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: "html-loader"
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',          
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: dev ? [] : ["**/*"]
      }),
      new CustomFunctionsMetadataPlugin({
        output: "functions.json",
        input: "./src/functions/functions.ts"
      }),
      new EnvironmentPlugin({
        NODE_ENV: env.NODE_ENV || 'local'
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "functions.html",
        template: "./src/functions/functions.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "functions"]
      }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
          to: "[name]." + buildType + ".[ext]",
          from: "manifest*.xml",
          transform(content) {
            if (dev) {
              return content;
            } else {
              return content.toString().replace(new RegExp(urlDev, "g"), urlProd);
            }
          }
        }
      ]),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "commands.html",
        template: "./src/commands/commands.html",
        chunks: ["polyfill", "commands"]
      })
    ],
    devServer: {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },      
      https: (options.https !== undefined) ? options.https : await devCerts.getHttpsServerOptions(),
      port: process.env.npm_package_config_dev_server_port || 4000
    }
  };

  return config;
};
```

Main.ts File:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store/index";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
(window as any).Office.onReady(() => {
  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    vuetify,
    render: (h) => h(App),
  }).$mount("#app");
});
```

tsconfig.json - add-in

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "lib",
    "lib-amd"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json - taskpane

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "node"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

The Add-In folder holds the custom functions and the Taskpane folder holds the Vuejs app. I have left out other default files and added these because I believe they will help communicate my possible issue.

**Steps To Merge:**

I have edited Manifest.xml following the steps provided on Microsofts documentation.
Updated name to use SharedRuntime

```
<Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1"/>
```

Added Runtimes tags within the Host tag

```
<Runtimes>
    <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
</Runtimes>
```

Updated the Page tag to use Taskpane.Url

```
<Page>
    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
</Page>
```

Updated the FunctionFile tag with Taskpane.Url

```
<FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
```

In webpack.config.js:
I have removed the HtmlWebpackPlugin references and replaced with the following.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
filename: "index.html",
template: "../taskpane/public/index.html",
chunks: ["polyfill", "taskpane", "commands", "functions"]
})
```

**Steps I did not provided in the Documentation:**
Since the project was created using the yeoman office generator with the customfunctions option selected, I believe I needed to add the following to the webpack.config.js file's entry object:

```
entry: {
    functions: "./src/functions/functions.ts",
    polyfill: "@babel/polyfill",
    commands: "./src/commands/commands.ts",
    taskpane: "../taskpane/src/main.ts"    <----- new addition
```

**Problem:**
When I try to build the project it throws errors such as:

ERROR in ../taskpane/src/main.ts
Module build failed
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for main.ts

Module not found errors

Property doesn't exist errors

**More Info:**

I'm thinking (but would love to confirm) that the steps I took to create the shared runtime provided by the documentation are indeed correct, along with adding the taskpane file to the entry object in the webpack config. But I just can't figure out why it won't compile. I'm thinking it has to do with the different tsconfig.json configurations. The addin is using target: "es5" while taskpane is using target: "esnext". There are other differences as well. If somebody can help me with this and needs that information, I will be more than happy to add it.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Thanks for helping look into this! I have added the rest of the folder structure, along with my webpack config prior to the additions listed in the description.

Comment: There is. I have added that to the description as well.

Comment: Sure thing, I have added tsconfig for both taskpane and add-in.

Comment: Honestly, I'm a bit out of my league, you may need to bounty, but I did see this which may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969071/module-build-failed-error-typescript-emitted-no-output-for

Comment: Thanks for helping look into it! If I'm able to implement anything that fixes it from the link you provided, I'll be sure to report back.