# Webpack is throwing a error upon bundlig my React app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

First time webpack user here.
I'm trying to bundle my React application with Webpack.

Here is my webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Here is my index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

When I try to bundle the project with `npx webpack --mode development`, I always get this error:

```
asset bundle.js 1.71 KiB [compared for emit] (name: main)
./src/index.tsx 39 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /home/palli/Desktop/DankSkins/frontend/src/index.tsx.
    at makeSourceMapAndFinish (/home/palli/Desktop/DankSkins/frontend/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:52:18)
    at successLoader (/home/palli/Desktop/DankSkins/frontend/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:39:5)
    at Object.loader (/home/palli/Desktop/DankSkins/frontend/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:5)

webpack 5.84.0 compiled with 1 error in 6041 ms
```

ChatGPT was unable to help me with this one.

Edit: SOLVED, had to override compilerOptions, as suggested by first answerer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67773129/7034621